# How to add CSS styles to a PHP code within a loop?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to apply css styles to a php loop:

```
<h3 class='title'></h3>
```

However this does not seem to be applying the css style:

```
.title{
    color : red;
}
```

I have tried putting `<?php ?>` tags around the echo and then applying the css but that still doesnt work.

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 10;";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<p></p> ";
                        echo "<h3 class='title'>Event name: </h3>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['eventname'];
                        echo "<p></p> ";
                        echo "<h3 class='title'>Event Venue: </h3>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['venue'];
                        echo " <p></p>";
                        echo "<h3 class='title'>Event Date: </h3>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['date'];
                        echo " <p></p>";
                        echo "<b>Event Description: </b>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['eventdescription'];
                }
            }


        ?>
```

Comment: Hello,    Have  you tried below code.  <?php echo "<style>.title{ color : 'red';}</style>" ?>

Comment: d joe  so what problem you are facing?Seems to be working fine

Comment: is <h3 class='title'>Event name: </h3> is showing in your out?

Comment: @javedrathod yup doesnt work :(

Comment: @djoe  what is not working can you explain? your records are printing or not?

Comment: @Anuresh nope it just comes out black. the text doesnt show as red

Comment: @AlivetoDie the text doesnt show as red is just black

Comment: so you are applying css on the same page or in a css file which is included to this code page?

Comment: @d joe Please write your css after the loop.

Comment: @joe is the class for h3 tag showing up? just try hard refresh (ctrl+f5)

Comment: 1. it's either cache problem so do `ctrl+shift+r`. Or may be the css file non added properly.

Comment: @d joe i tried <?php echo "<style>.title{ color : 'red';}</style>" ?> this code in my local and its working fine.

Comment: @javedrathod so do i put the text (event name) between the tags? like <?php echo "<style>event name.title{ color : 'red';}</style>" ?>

Comment: @d joe Yes Right!!!

Comment: Just try in Mozilla Console, when your loop is executed try to give another property from it. If it not works then there is some other mistake. And if it works then i think its not taking property as it is declared before.

Comment: I can't see the problem in here. It works for me. See [Teh Playground](https://tehplayground.com/2AEeNaMDeeUPX2sa) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use a colon (`:`) instead of an equal sign to assign a CSS property value:

```
.title {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @djoe This doesn't seem like an issue related to PHP. Try inspecting a `.title` element using the developer tools of your browser. Check to see if something else overrides the `color` property in the element styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<style>h3.title{ color : red;}</style>"; ?>
```

Use This Code

Comment: the text just disappears when i do that ? not sure why

Comment: Which text disappear? Please remove single quotes from red and try !important property after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 10;";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<p></p> ";
                        echo "<h3 style='color:#ff0000' class='title'>Event name: </h3>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['eventname'];
                        echo "<p></p> ";
                        echo "<h3 style='color:#ff0000' class='title'>Event Venue: </h3>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['venue'];
                        echo " <p></p>";
                        echo "<h3 style='color:#ff0000' class='title'>Event Date: </h3>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['date'];
                        echo " <p></p>";
                        echo "<b>Event Description: </b>";
                        echo " ";
                        echo $row['eventdescription'];
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: The suggestion here is to add `style='color:#ff0000'`. This would make sense if there's another `.title` rule with higher priority.

Comment: Explain your answer too else its hard to other to  understand.